# Markov Transient State using Stationary Distribution

Tags: matrices, markov-chains

I have the following Discrete Time Markov Chain with  $a^{(0)} = \  $$ \begin{pmatrix}
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0
\end{pmatrix} $

$$ P = 
\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 1/2 & 1/2 & 0 & 0 \\
1/2 & 0 & 0 & 1/2 & 0 \\
1/2 & 0 & 0 & 1/2 & 0 \\
0 & 1/4 & 1/4 & 0 & 1/2 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
\end{pmatrix}
$$

Using the fact that this DTMC is irreducible and periodic with $k=2$  , I found the stationarydistribution as: $$ 
\begin{pmatrix}
1/6 & 1/6 & 1/6 & 1/6 &2/6
\end{pmatrix}
$$

I am now asked to figure out  $ a^{(3)} $ , which I know is defined as $ a^{(0)}P^3 $, but I am asked specifically to do this without calculating $ P^3 $. Can I use the stationary distribution to show that  $ a^{(3)} $, in this case, equals $$ \begin{pmatrix}
0  & 5/16 & 5/16 & 0 &3/8
\end{pmatrix} \ \ ?$$

Comment: How do you plan to use the stationary distribution exactly?

Answer (score 1):

We do not need to compute $P^3$ explicitily.

$$a^{(0)}P^3=(((a^{(0)})P)P)P$$

The computation involves $3$ vector-matrix product.

That is first we compute $a^{(1)}$ then use it to compute $a^{(2)}$ and finally use it compute $a^{(3)}$.